# How would you incorporate dropzone js or upload a profile picture in a Laravel 5.1 application and display it?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dropzone.js, laravel-5.1

I am creating a Laravel 5.1 application and I want to upload and display a profile picture for a user using Dropzone js or any other method.  I would really appreciate code examples, if that's possible. Thx in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for:

**DropZone and Laravel 3:**

http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/howto-ajax-multiple-file-upload-in-laravel/

**How to adjust for Laravel 4:**

http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/uploading-files-in-laravel-4/ there is a lot of code there for you.

Even though you're working with Laravel 5.1, I don't think there will be any major differences after you make the Laravel 4 adjustments.

I'm assuming you already know you can just download the Dropzone JS into the public folder in your Laravel project and access it from there.  If you get stuck anywhere, let me know.

From the above links, here is some key points:

**Your FORM in your view:**

```
<form action="{{ url('user/upload')}}" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

"At this point if you go to the view where you implemented the dropzone plugin you should see it working. But it should give you errors when you try to upload files because the action where it tries to upload doesn’t exist yet. Now we need to hook up the form to a route or controller."

**Your Controller method from the route '/user/upload'**

```
$file = Input::file('file');
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
// If the uploads fail due to file system, you can try doing public_path().'/uploads' 
$filename = str_random(12);
//$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
//$extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
$upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

if( $upload_success ) {
   return Response::json('success', 200);
} else {
   return Response::json('error', 400);
}
```

Comment: @WilliamDas My pleasure ;) let me know if you need more help.